# Chrome App - webview.cleardata, reload and periodic refresh

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I'm working on a kiosk app with a webview to display a Google Slides presentation. Basic mechanics are all working fine, but I need for the webview to refresh periodically to reflect changes made to the Slides.

Watched Chromium bug [406437](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=406437) to clear webview cache (yay!), and am attempting to implement the webview.cleardata and webview.reload, but doesn't seem to work. Console log shows "Cannot read property 'reload' of null"

Am I on the right track? Is there something simple I'm overlooking, or is there a design flaw in my logic?

Contents of my **browser.js** (at least the first part)...

```
// NOTE: Refresh timing is on line 26 - in milliseconds
// 5 min: 5 x 60 (sec) x 1000 (ms)

window.onresize = doLayout;
var isLoading = false;

// Define the function
function refreshWebView() {
  var webview = document.querySelector('webview');

  // https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/webview-samples/browser/browser.js
  // Set up the clear data variable
  var clearDataType = { 
  appcache: true, 
  cookies: true, 
  fileSystems: true, 
  indexedDB: true, 
  localStorage: true, 
  webSQL: true, 
  cache: true
  } 

  webview.clearData({since: 0}, clearDataType, function() { webview.reload(true); }); 
  webview.reload(true);
  setTimeout(function() { refreshWebView(); }, 60*1000);
}

// Kick off the refresh (with the delay defined above)
console.log('starting refreshWebView...');

refreshWebView();

onload = function() {
  var webview = document.querySelector('webview');
  doLayout();

  document.querySelector('#back').onclick = function() {
    webview.back();
  };

... remaining code removed for brevity...
```

Comment: Well, it might be the common callback issue when the variable gets gabage-collected after some time. Try one of the standard solutions: `webview.clearData({since: 0}, clearDataType, webview.reload.bind(webview, true));`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll give that a shot. The actual error is: 
`Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'clearData' of null`
so it doesn't look like it's even loading the first time.